# C not allocating memory for new char array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, crypt

I don't see how the following code works w.r.t. the char array `cd2` being overwritten. I am trying to just allocate space for two strings and then to populate them with the results of the `crypt` function.  I am not sure how big a part `crypt` plays here or if this would some other string manipulation function.  But the below output should not be the same, **they should have different values.  But they are both "ttxtRM6GAOLtI", and I was trying to get one output to start with "ss"**.

```
#include <crypt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    char *cd;  
    cd = malloc(30 * sizeof(*cd));
    char *cd2; 
    cd2 = malloc(30 * sizeof(*cd2));

    cd2 = crypt("yum", "ss");
    cd = crypt("yum", "tt");

    printf("hasehd 'yum' with 'tt' salt is %s\n",cd);
    printf("hasehd 'yum' with 'ss' salt is %s\n",cd2);

}
```

output -

```
   hasehd 'yum' with 'tt' salt is ttxtRM6GAOLtI
   hasehd 'yum' with 'ss' salt is ttxtRM6GAOLtI
```

UPDATE: I changed it to not use malloc but I think I have to allocate still the memory via a declaration of a char array.  Since `crypt` overwrites a static buffer I needed to give the results somewhere else before it was overwritten.

```
#include <crypt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
 char ch1[30];
 char ch2[30];
 char *cd;
 char *cd2;
 cd = &ch1[0];  
 cd2 = &ch2[0]; 

 snprintf(cd2, 12, "%s\n", crypt("yum", "ss"));
 snprintf(cd, 12, "%s\n", crypt("yum", "tt"));

 printf("hasehd 'yum' with 'tt' salt is %s\n",cd);
 printf("hasehd 'yum' with 'ss' salt is %s\n",cd2);

}
```

output -

```
hasehd 'yum' with 'tt' salt is ttxtRM6GAOL
hasehd 'yum' with 'ss' salt is ssqDHVWOCwe
```

UPDATE: I used `strcpy` as was recommended and I used malloc to allocate the space for the array. `strcpy` seems a little cleaner because I don't need to provide the length.

```
#include <crypt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
  int PWORD_LENGTH = 30;

   char *cd;
   char *cd2;
   cd = malloc(sizeof(char) * (PWORD_LENGTH + 1));
   cd2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (PWORD_LENGTH + 1));

   strcpy(cd2, crypt("yum", "ss"));
   strcpy(cd, crypt("yum", "tt"));

   printf("hasehd 'yum' with 'tt' salt is %s\n",cd);
   printf("hasehd 'yum' with 'ss' salt is %s\n",cd2);

}
```

output -

```
hasehd 'yum' with 'tt' salt is ttxtRM6GAOL
hasehd 'yum' with 'ss' salt is ssqDHVWOCwe
```

Comment: `cd2 = crypt("yum", "ss");`-->`strcpy(cd2, crypt("yum", "ss"));`  do the same for `cd` also.

Comment: The memory allocation was useless, since you immediately overwrite the pointers, with the values returned by `crypt()`.

Comment: I don't know the `crypt` function but since you assign to `cd` / `cd2` it must return a pointer and that means that your `malloc` is wrong - unnecessary I guess. Unless you call `crypt` incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crypt()` returns a pointer to a statically allocated buffer.  Each call to `crypt()` overwrites the previous result.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html

> The return value points to static data whose content is overwritten by
>   each call.

Your `malloc` calls, in this case, are not needed. In fact, you end up with unreachable memory that you now can not `free` because you overwrote the pointers with the result from `crypt()`

Comment: But don't I have to store them somewhere else because the crypt call will just overwrite them?

Comment: `strcpy` the result somewhere.  so rather than overwriting the `cd` pointer, `strcpy` into it.

Comment: No, technically it's less efficient than `strncpy` because it has to parse the format string.  Practically, the difference won't really be noticeable unless you're doing a lot of these.

Answer (score 1):

`crypt()` function has internal memory, each call overwrites previous result.

Either call `crypt()` and `printf()` for 'ss' then for 'tt'

Or use reentrant version

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <crypt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *cd;
    cd = malloc(30 * sizeof(*cd));
    char *cd2;
    cd2 = malloc(30 * sizeof(*cd2));

    struct crypt_data *data = calloc(1, sizeof (struct crypt_data));
    struct crypt_data *data2 = calloc(1, sizeof (struct crypt_data));

    cd2 = crypt_r("yum", "ss", data2);
    cd = crypt_r("yum", "tt", data);

    printf("hasehd 'yum' with 'ss' salt is %s\n",cd2);
    printf("hasehd 'yum' with 'tt' salt is %s\n",cd);

}
```

Comment: You still have memory leak.